# Hamming Distance Intuition

Tags: c++

I have recently stumbled across this code snippet [found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) and wanted to get some clarification as to what is happening:

```
int hamming_distance(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
int dist = 0;
unsigned  val = x ^ y;

// Count the number of bits set
while (val != 0)
{
    // A bit is set, so increment the count and clear the bit
    dist++;
    val &= val - 1;
}

// Return the number of differing bits
return dist;
}
```

What is the significance of performing an XOR operation on both of the inputs?

Comment: I'd say the XOR is the simple part of this algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function basically returns the number of **differing bits** between the input numbers.

This is achieved with **XOR**-ing the two numbers which will generate an output where only those bits will set to 1 that differ (check the table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate)).

From then on it is just **counting** the bits in the output produced by XOR and returning them.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thanks a bunch

Comment: Although I think harold is right, the way it's counting the bits is a more interesting part of the function.

Comment: So what's the significance of counting the bits in that manner?

Comment: @User5842 You can find an explanation [here](http://goursaha.freeoda.com/Miscellaneous/IntegerBitCount.html).